# Matlab Database QueryDb error

Tags: mysql, sql, matlab

I need to insert some data into a mysql database. Db is connected and working.
I am running the following code :

```
a = sprintf('%s',hashedStr); 
sqlQueryStr = 'insert into products (security_code) values (a)'
QueryDB(sqlQueryStr);
```

I have a database called test and a table named products with 2 fields id and security_code.

When I run this, I get :

```
Unknown column 'a' in fieldlist ...
```

Why is this happening ? i don`t have and don`t need this column ...

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
sqlQueryStr = sprintf('insert into products (security_code) values ("%s")',hashedStr); 
QueryDB(sqlQueryStr);
```

problem is that you are not replacing "a" variable into sql expression